# Custom View not appearing

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, custom-controls

Here is the XML for the layout in which I want my custom view to appear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:rs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.bookcessed.booksearch"
    android:id="@+id/widget273"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/csp_tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose Your Source"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#ffc83200"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="15dip"
        android:paddingBottom="75dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <com.bookcessed.booksearch.SearchProviderButton
        android:id="@+id/csp_spb_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/csp_tv_title"
        rs:providerName="BOOKP" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the custom view's XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:rs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.bookcessed.booksearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/pv_rl_strings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pv_tv_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pv_tv_and"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#ff11ab37"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pv_tv_and"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" and "
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:paddingRight="6dip"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pv_tv_browse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Browse"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#ff0077bb"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pv_tv_and" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pv_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pv_tv_search"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pv_tv_and"
            android:src="@drawable/bookp_logo" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/pv_rl_genres"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pv_rl_strings"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pv_genre1"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pv_genre2"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pv_genre1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pv_genre3"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pv_genre2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pv_genre4"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pv_genre3" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pv_genre5"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pv_genre4" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pv_genre6"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pv_genre5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pv_genre7"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pv_genre6" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pv_genre8"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pv_genre7" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pv_genre9"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pv_genre8" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the class SearchProviderButton:

```
public class SearchProviderButton extends LinearLayout {

 private Connector connector;
 private Context context;
 private View inflatedView;

 public SearchProviderButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);

  TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.SearchProviderButton);
  connector = SearchProvider.valueOf(a.getString(R.styleable.SearchProviderButton_providerName)).getConnector();

  this.context = context;
  setFocusable(true);
  setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  setVisibility(VISIBLE);

  //setOnClickListener(listenerAdapter);
  setClickable(true);

 }



 @Override
 protected void onFinishInflate() {
  super.onFinishInflate();

  LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  inflatedView = li.inflate(R.layout.provider_view, null);


  ImageView logo = (ImageView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.pv_logo);
  logo.setImageResource(connector.getLogoDrawableID());


  TextView searchTV = (TextView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.pv_tv_search);
  TextView andTV = (TextView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.pv_tv_and);
  if(!connector.isSearchSupported()){
   andTV.setText("");
   searchTV.setVisibility(GONE);
  }

  setgenreIcons();
 }



 public Connector getConnector(){
  return connector;
 }

 public void setConnector(Connector connector){
  this.connector = connector;
 }


 private void setgenreIcons(){
  int[] genreIconDrawables = {R.id.pv_genre1,R.id.pv_genre2, R.id.pv_genre3,
    R.id.pv_genre4, R.id.pv_genre5, R.id.pv_genre6, R.id.pv_genre7, 
    R.id.pv_genre8, R.id.pv_genre9};  

  ArrayList<Genre> availgenre = connector.getAvailablegenres();
  availgenre.remove(Genre.ALL);

  int counter = 0;
  for(int genreIVid : genreIconDrawables){
   ImageView curgenreImageView = (ImageView)inflatedView.findViewById(genreIVid);
   if(counter < availgenre.size() - 1){
    curgenreImageView.setImageResource(availgenre.get(counter).getDrawable());
   } else {
    curgenreImageView.setVisibility(GONE);
   }
   counter++; 
  }
 }

 protected void onFocusChanged(boolean gainFocus, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
  if (gainFocus == true){
   this.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 165, 0));
  } else {
   this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
  }
 }


}
```

Here is the code for the class loading the xml that contains my custom component:

```
bookPServiceProviderButton = (SearchProviderButton)findViewById(R.id.csp_spb_1);
bookPServiceProviderButton.setOnClickListener(SPBOnClickListener);
bookPServiceProviderButton.setConnector(new bookPConnector());
bookPServiceProviderButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

EDIT: After the first comment, I added this code:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

}
```

Now it has a width and a height, but nothing is showing up inside of it!

Comment: The heirarchy viewer, found in the tools folder, might help you out here.  It visualized the view tree for you.  Its possible that your view things it has 0 width and height, or something like that.

Comment: Yes it does have 0 width, and 0 height. How do I make wrap_content wrap my content? (Thanks for the tip by the way this thing is nifty)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your custom layout view is not appearing because you're not putting anything into it. In your `onFinishInflate` you have the line `inflatedView = li.inflate(R.layout.provider_view, null);` But you don't add that to your view. You have two options to add the views to your custom layout view.

Change your custom view to extend `RelativeLayout`, change the enclosing `RelativeLayout` to [`<merge>`](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html) in your provider_view.xml, and fix your `findViewId` lines in to `this.findViewId(...)` since the views will be inflated into your layout.

In your layout xml do:

```
<com.bookcessed.booksearch.SearchProviderButton
android:id="@+id/csp_spb_1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/csp_tv_title"
rs:providerName="BOOKP">
    <!-- include this so it's added to your custom layout view -->
    <include layout="@layout/provider_view" />
</com.bookcessed.booksearch.SearchProviderButton>
```

provider_view becomes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:rs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.bookcessed.booksearch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/pv_rl_strings"
  .
  .
  .
</merge>
```

SearchProviderButton:

```
public class SearchProviderButton extends RelativeLayout{
 .
 .
 .

 @Override
 protected void onFinishInflate() {
  super.onFinishInflate();

  //the <include> in the layout file has added these views to this 
  //so search this for the views
  ImageView logo = this.findViewById(R.id.pv_logo);
  logo.setImageResource(connector.getLogoDrawableID());


  TextView searchTV = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.pv_tv_search);
  TextView andTV = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.pv_tv_and);
  if(!connector.isSearchSupported()){
   andTV.setText("");
   searchTV.setVisibility(GONE);
  }

  setgenreIcons();
 }
 .
 .
 .
```

Or you could properly inflate the view in `onCreate` by `layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.provider_view, this, true)`. That call will inflate the referenced layout into the passed `ViewGroup`, in this case your custom view, and add the inflated `View`s to it. Then you can fix up the `findViewId` calls in your `onFinishInflate`.

Comment: I think I've tried both ways of doing it, but probably not doing it correctly. I can't get it.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include examples of the necessary changes for the first method.

Comment: THANK YOU! I hope that someone might help you as much as you just helped me! Thank you soooo much. I would never have been able to put 2 and 2 together myself. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you know why my custom view is extremely tall? could have something to do with onMeasure? I tried to fit one more underneath the first, but its offscreen

Comment: Try removing your onMeasure that you added since it wasn't the actual problem. I haven't actually tried running your layout so I'm not sure how tall it should be. It looks like it should not be too much more than 30px.

Answer (score 5):

TC... Sometimes it wont show in the preview unless you run it.

Comment: exactly!! I had a correct xml structure, but nothing showed up until the first run. Must be an Android Studio bug

Answer (score 2):

For wrap_content to work, you need to properly implement the `measure` and `layout` functions for your custom View.  See [How Android Draws Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html) for details on what these methods mean.

My guess would be that `getMeasureWidth()` and `getMeasureHeight()` functions for your view are always returning 0.